# How to perform Constrained Optimization by Jacobian like Matlab?

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, optimization

I have a code for doing constrained optimization in Matlab:

this one is for objective function from deriving a function according to the constraint and the case:

```
function f=funcobj(X);
    f=[(2-3*X(1)*2+X(3)*(1-X(1))+X(4)*(5+X(1)/5));
    (3-4*X(2)+3*X(3)+2*X(4));
    (X(1)+3*X(2)-X(1).^2/2-5.5);
    (5*X(1)+2*X(2)+X(1).^2/10-10)];
end
```

and this one is the Jacobian function

```
function [f0,jac]=jacobian(x);
h = 1.0e-4;
n = length(x);
jac = zeros(n,n);
f0 = funcobj(x);
for zz=1:n;
    temp = x(zz);
    x(zz)= temp + h;
    f1 = funcobj(x);
    x(zz)= temp;
    jac(:,zz) = (f1 - f0)/h;
    disp((f1 - f0)/h);
end
% disp(jac)
```

and this one is the main code

```
clc;close all;clear all
%initial
X(1,:)= [1 1 1 1]';
niter=30;tol=1e-6;
for ii=1:niter-1
    disp(X(ii,:));
    [f,dp]=jacobian(X(ii,:));
    dX=inv(dp)*f;
    X(ii+1,:)=X(ii, :)'-dX;
    fprintf('Iterasion=ti Solution=$.4f \n',ii,X(ii+1))
    if abs(X(ii+1,:)-X(ii,:))<tol;
        r=X(ii+1,:);
        disp('The Solution is convergent')
        break
    end
end
x=r(1);y=r(2);lambda_1=r(3);lambda_2=r(4);
f = (2*x)+(3*y)-(x).^3-2*(y.^2);
disp('Case 1')
disp(['x=' num2str(x) ', y = ' num2str(y),',f = ' num2str(f)])
disp(['lambda_1 = ' num2str(lambda_1), ', lambda_2 = ' num2str(lambda_2)])
```

When I try to convert it to Python, I still confused with the X array and how to rewrite jacobian in Python. This is my attempt:

```
import numpy as np
def funcobj(z):
    f = np.array([[2-3*z[0]**2 + z[2]*(1-z[0])+z[3]*(5+z[0]/5)], [(-4*z[1]+3*z[2]+2*z[3])], [z[0]+3*z[1]-(z[2]**2)/2-5.5], [5*z[0]+2*z[1]+(z[0]**2)/10-10]])
    print(f)
    return f

def jacobian(X):
    h = 1.0e-4
    n = len(X)
    print(n)
    jac = np.zeros([4,4])
    f0 = funcobj(X)
    for i in range(0,n):
        temp = X[i]
        X[i] = temp + h
        f1 = funcobj(X)
        X[i] = temp
        #print((f1-f0)/h)
        jac[0,i] = (f1-f0)/h
    return (f0, jac)

X=np.array([[1],[1],[1],[1]])
niter=30
tol=1e-6
for i in range(0,niter):
 jacobian(X[:,i])
 if abs(X[:,i]-X[:,i-1])<tol:
     r=X[:,i]
     print('The Solution is convergent')
     break
```

How to fix this code? I still get the error in Python

Answer (score 1):

Your `funcobj` returns a np.ndarray with shape `(n,1)` instead of `(n,)`. Note that contrary to matlab, in numpy, the former corresponds to a matrix while the latter corresponds to a vector. Next, in the line `jac[0, i] = (f1-f0)/h` you are trying to assign a np.ndarray to a single matrix element. It should be `jac[:, i]` instead. Note also that `range` starts by default at 0 since python has 0-based indexing.

In code:

```py
def funcobj(z):
    f1 = 2-3*z[0]**2 + z[2]*(1-z[0])+z[3]*(5+z[0]/5)
    f2 = (-4*z[1]+3*z[2]+2*z[3])
    f3 = z[0]+3*z[1]-(z[2]**2)/2-5.5
    f4 = 5*z[0]+2*z[1]+(z[0]**2)/10-10
    return np.array((f1, f2, f3, f4))

def jacobian(X):
    h = 1.0e-4
    n = len(X)
    jac = np.zeros([4,4])
    f0 = funcobj(X)
    for i in range(n):
        temp = X[i]
        X[i] = temp + h
        f1 = funcobj(X)
        X[i] = temp
        #print((f1-f0)/h)
        jac[:,i] = (f1-f0)/h
    return (f0, jac)

x0 = np.ones(4)
# works as expected
print(jacobian(x0))
```

Now it's your turn to go on from here and implement the main algorithm in python.

Comment: Now I already fix the X array by adding float datatype, so the sum is working with small number. I also modify the conditional if so it works by moving the column in i-looping. The problem is how the dX in Matlab works? I print the dX value in Matlab it somehow change the multiplication of the inverse of `jac` matrix and `f0`. The `jac` matrix size changing from 4x4 to 1x4. Which one is a mistake in my code?

Comment: `X=np.array([[1],[1],[1],[1]])
niter=30
tol=1e-6
X = X.astype(float)
for i in range(0,niter):
    f0, jac = jacobian(X[:,i-1])
    print(f0)
    print(jac)
    dX=(np.linalg.inv(jac))@(f0)
    print(dX)
    X[:,i-1]=X[:,i-1]-dX
    if abs((X[:][i]) - (X[:][i-1]))<tol:
        r=X[:,i]
        print('The Solution is convergent')
        break`

Comment: You probably want `norm(X(ii+1,:)-X(ii,:)) < tol` instead of `abs(X(ii+1,:)-X(ii,:))<tol`, so you should fix your Matlab code first and then reimplement it in Python. However, this goes beyond the scope of the comments section. Please post a separate question if you need help.